# Keep myself right on this train

Tags: idioms, lyrics

In *Underdog*, a song by Kasabian, I have some difficulties to understand the meaning of

> Kill me if you dare

ok

> Hold my head up everywhere

- Is it an ellipsis for "I hold my head up everywhere", meaning that I won't look down
- or is it "Kill me and hold my head up", meaning you kill me and you show my cut head on a spike, like in medieval age?

> Keep myself right on this train

What does this mean?

Comment: Lyrics and poems are hard to interpret without the full context. There are sometimes metaphors involved that are obscure unless the rest of the song/poem is considered.

Comment: True, but these 3 sentences make the full 1st verse. I don't have more context.

Comment: Criticism and analysis are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇  The FAQ says "Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature" are "out of scope" but the question is not about literature.

Comment: @jwpat7: I'd say interpreting poetry and lyrics falls under that rule.

Comment: @JasperLoy music.stackexchange.com are for topics about practice & performance, composition, technique, theory, and history. Explaining the meaning of sentences, even lyrics, is definitely out of scope there.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I'm not asking for [criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_criticism), discussion nor [analysis](http://www.roanestate.edu/owl/ElementsLit.html). I'm just asking for an explaination in plain English. Is this community going to close all the questions typed "what does ... mean?"

Comment: @rds: Not all questions. But song lyrics typically have highly subjective meanings and there's no way to arrive at consensus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the second line of this song is an ellipsis for : *I ('ll) hold my head up everywhere.* I take this to mean I will keep my pride, or something along these lines.

As for the third line, it looks like the speaker has chosen a particular course of action and is not going to change it, that's what the train can be interpreted as. There is no idiom involved, at least not that I know of.

All this with many reservations.